# Google Vision product search indexing

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-product-search

I have a question regarding Google Vision product search.
I know the Product Search index of products is updated approximately every 30 minutes. Does indexTime reset to default value "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z" on an unused ProductSet?

Answer (score 0):

That means that it hasn't been indexed yet

Comment: Its says the cycle is every 30 mins (approx.) but mine was not updated for 2 hours. Is the first search necessary to queue for indexing next time (next cycle)?